# How do I dynamically layer objects ontop of eachother in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, dynamic, windows-forms-designer

I'm using a FlowLayoutPanel to dynamically display an array of PictureBoxes and Labels. They're going in the order: PictureBox-Label-PictureBox-Label and so on. I need those labels to appear above each picture so they'll match, basically layring them ontop of picturebox margins. I tried using `Controls.SetChildIndex(temp, 2);` but it seem to just swap the postion of the picturebox. I also tried using `temp.BringToFront();` but then all the pictureboxes being displayed at the top of the panel and all the labels are below (I need each label to match each picturebox above them). Here's the code:

```
 public void RunMeta()
    {
        Label mostPickedLabel = new Label();
        mostPickedLabel.Text = "Most picked heroes";
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(mostPickedLabel);
        mostPickedLabel.Margin = new Padding(15, 0, 1000, 0);
        mostPickedLabel.Font = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 15);
        mostPickedLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkCyan;
        mostPickedLabel.Size = new Size(200, 30);
        foreach (var mostPickedHero in FetchDataFromDota2Site.MostUsedHeroesAndImages)
        {
            PictureBox temp = new PictureBox();
            temp.ImageLocation = mostPickedHero.ImageSource;
            temp.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            temp.Left = temp.Width * flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count;
            temp.Margin = new Padding(15, 30, 15, 30);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(temp);
            flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
            Label heroName = new Label();
            heroName.Text = mostPickedHero.MostPickedHeroName;
            heroName.Font = new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 8);
            heroName.ForeColor = Color.White;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(heroName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a UserControl containing the label and picture box

Comment: Isn't it WPF only? I'm using Windows Forms. I'm also not familiar with it to be honest.

Comment: You should take a look here: [WinForms UserControl Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: think it actually wouldn't work, i have all my pictures and text stored in one place (MostUsedHeroesAndImages) so i can't make 1 user control display 1 set of picture+text, they're all being displayed at once

Comment: actually nevermind, i figured that out, thank you for the solution